# The Irrationality of 2

Tags: soft-question, irrational-numbers

I am sorry it is not 'research level'. A quick answer will do. When I attempt using the Square root of 2 method to prove the rationality of Square root of 4 according to how it was done in a book, 2 became Irrational. I think it has to do with primality but all the proofs I have seen didn't mention that. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Sorry I don't know if I understand. We have $\sqrt{4}=\sqrt{2^2}=2$ which is rational, as desired. I just used $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ for $a\ge 0$. What else is there to show? You are trying to adapt the proof of _irrationality_ of $\sqrt{2}$ to prove _rationality_ of $\sqrt{4}$ ? It doesn't seem natural to me at all.

Comment: Let's recall how we prove irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$. We assume $\sqrt{2}=m/n$ where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and then get $m^2=2n^2$. So $m$ is even, which gives $m=2k$ for some integer $k$, and thus $4k^2=2n^2$, and $2k^2=n^2$. And so $n$ must be even, contradicting our hypothesis that $m$ and $n$ had no prime factor in common. Now, let's try to attempt to "prove" irrationality of $\sqrt{4}$ (we will be doomed) in the exact same way. Note that $\sqrt{4}=m/n$ would lead to $m^2=4n^2$. So $m$ is even, $m=2k$ and thus $4k^2=4n^2$, and we conclude $k^2=n^2$. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] But $k^2=n^2$ doesn't give any information to us about $n$. In particular, we cannot deduce $n$ is even (because $k$ need not be even). So our attempt fails, and rightly so, for $\sqrt{4}$ is rational. I hope this helps!

Comment: @robjohn: I don't think the question is a duplicate of the linked question. I think the question here is supposed to be: "Why does the prove of irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ not apply to $\sqrt 4$?" This question is already answered above by Prism, though.

Comment: The least the OP could do would be to write down their imitation of the classical proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt2$ "showing" $\sqrt4$ is irrational. This seems to be much needed if one wants the OP to get anything at all from explanations such as the (excellent) ones provided by Prism in the comments.

Comment: Thank you Prism. But why didn't you just say 'm is a multiple of 4' instead of 'm is even'. Most people that learn the proof don't actually know why it works. For example: how was the co-primality information used?. And how does your method work for the Square root of 9?

Comment: Hi Xmario, I didn't say $m$ is multiple of $4$, because $m^2$ being divisible by $4$ does **not** imply that $m$ is multiple of $4$. Take $x=6$, as a counterexample. This is precisely because $4$ is not a prime! Also, T. Bongers has given you excellent answer above.

Comment: @T. Bongers Great exposition. I was very dissatisfied with the popular proofs around that don't mention what you said. How does one extend it to the Sqrt(9)?

Comment: @Xmario It's essentially the same, with $2$ replaced by $3$, and $4$ replaced by $9$.

Comment: Thanks. Primality is an important factor then. The question is answered. However out of curiosity, Is the Square root of 8 irrational? (Given that it is an integral multiple of the sqrt(2))

Answer (score 4):

The technique to show that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational is as follows:

Suppose that $\sqrt{2} = \frac a b$, and square to get $2b^2 = a^2$. Conclude that $2 | a^2$, so therefore, $2$ must be a divisor of $a$ (question for the reader: Why does $2 | a^2 \implies 2 | a$?). Proceed to show that $2 | b$, a contradiction.

Now when we try the same technique with $\sqrt{4}$, we conclude that $4 b^2 = a^2$, so $4 | a^2$. Now, however, this does **not** imply that $4 | a$, so the proof breaks down. (An easy example is $a = 2$).

This is similar to what Prism stated in the comments.